# No branches in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Somehow I managed to make the branches disappear in SourceTree (the section on the left that lists file status, branches, tags, remotes and stashes).

See the screenshot:

[image]

How to make them come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reveal the hidden branches, all I had to do was drag the middle divider over like so:

[image]